# WPF Tab Control With No Tabs

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, tabcontrol

I would like to have a control similar to tab control but without the "TabStrip" part
and have the tabs be changed by a combo box instead.
how to I make this happen?

I guess that the answer is out there I just fail to correctly phrase it in English.

Comment: Could you describe better what's your goal?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Don't use a tabcontrol for this. Use a [ContentControl](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.contentcontrol.aspx) where you dynamically bind the content.

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding MyDynamicContent}" />
```

The change the item that is stored in the `MyDynamicContent` property based on the checkboxes.

Comment: Using TabControl you have to hide tabs etc. Sigh... I wish I'd known that before!

Answer (score 1):

You could also use a frame or grid or any of the content controls.   I like the ContentControl answer as it is the most basic control that holds content.