# WPF change control in modelview

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I created a solution that looks similar to [Binding ContentControl Content for dynamic content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15936428/binding-contentcontrol-content-for-dynamic-content). But I'm stuck with changing some things.

As example, I created a simple login command. Which works perfectly. I created a button which I binded to a login command.

```
    public RelayCommand LoginCommand {
        get {
            return new RelayCommand(Login);
        }
    }


    public void Login(object o) {
        if (Membership.ValidateUser(Username, Password)) {
            ErrorVisible = Visibility.Hidden;
        } else {
            ErrorVisible = Visibility.Visible;
        }
    }
```

I tested this, and it works great. But when a login is successful I would like to change the user control to something else. But I’ve no idea how to do this. How can I change the ContentControl content within my view model? So actually, replacing the current login control with another control.

Comment: You can overlay both controls in a grid and toggle the visibility of each from within your view model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can bind as usual:

```
<ContentControl Content="{Binding Path=PropertyWithUI}"/>
```

And in code:

```
public UIElement PropertyWithUI 
{
   get 
   { 
       return propertyWithUI;
   }
   set
   {
       propertyWithUI = value;
       // notify property changed here
   }
}
```

But it's not the best approach, it's better to place both controls on your window and bind theirs visibility property to properties in your VM.

**EDIT**:

Here is an example:

In XAML I have a content control and a button:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ContentControl Grid.Row="0" Content="{Binding Path=Control}"></ContentControl>
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Height="40" Click="Button_Click">Change control</Button>
</Grid>
```

And in code:

A tiny custom MVVM:

```
public class MyMVVM : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
        private UIElement control;
        public UIElement Control
        {
            get { return control; }
            set
            {
                if (control == value)
                    return;
                control = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("Control"));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }
```

And other window code. I create an instance of th VM and initialize Control property with a new TextBox;

```
    readonly MyMVVM mvvm = new MyMVVM();
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        DataContext = mvvm;
        mvvm.Control = new TextBox() {Text = "this is a text box"};
    }
```

When a user clicks I change control to other.

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        var wb = new WebBrowser();
        mvvm.Control = wb;
        wb.Navigate("http://stackoverflow.com");
    }
```

You can try it in home :) Create new WPF project and put the code above.

Comment: But this is to load another user control? My aim is to replace the control by another one. So when someone is logged in: replace content.