# Observable / notifying derived / computed property of EF entity class

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework

I am trying to use the .NET Entity Framework in a WPF application. I have some model classes that, depending on various properties, should be visible or invisible in some lists. For a single property - for example, a `bool` property - I was able to use a Converter that turns the `bool` value into a `Visibility` - fine so far.

The next challenge is that I need to implement more complex operations to determine whether a model element should be visible. A typical example might look like this:

```
public bool IsVisibleInProjectView
{
    get { return (!IsDeleted && IsSelectedForDisplay && Milestones.Any(ms => ms.IsVisibleInProjectView)); }
}
```

I was able to add this method to the generated partial class and use a Binding to influence the visibility. However, this has one drawback: Whenever one of the underlying properties is changed, whoever is listening to the "derived property" is not notified. I found several answers that suggested triggering the `OnPropertyChanged` event manually, but the generated EF classes are very lightweight and do not seem to implement the Interface `INotifyPropertyChanged` (anymore?) It seems like I'm missing something here - if the EF entities are not the ones issuing the notifications, who is?

I have also tried to add a computed property to the model (I'm using the model-first approach), but basically came full circle and ran into the same issue: How would I update the computed property whenever one of the base properties changes?

Comment: if you want to do this, it might be easier to follow the MVVM approach. i.e. have a light weight model, and create a ViewModel class that will implement INPC. The viewmodel class will be responsible for issuing the notifications. Another option would be to use styles with multiple data triggers on the XAML side to control visibility.

Comment: @failedprogramming Could you perhaps recommend a good introduction or tutorial? I've been trying to find something, but most of the stuff I found is either too simplified or not related to the EF at all...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15936428/binding-contentcontrol-content-for-dynamic-content/15960843#15960843) as I post an answer that demonstrates very simple MVVM. If you look at how my viewmodels wrap the HomePage and SettingsPage model, your viewmodels can work in a similiar way and wrap your EF models. This way your EF models can be very lightweight and do not need to implement INPC.

If you do have a computed property on the model, your viewmodel will just "wrap" that property to expose it to your xaml view - similar to how it wraps normal properties.

For your problem specifically, you would put these methods in the viewmodel class

```
public EfModelClass Model { get; private set; }

private bool _isVisibleInProjectView;

public bool IsVisibleInProjectView
{
    get { return _isVisibleInProjectView; }
    set { _isVisibleInProjectView; OnPropertyChanged("IsVisibleInProjectView");}
}

private void UpdateVisibility()
{
    IsVisibleInProjectView = 
        (!IsDeleted && IsSelectedForDisplay 
        && Milestones.Any(ms => ms.IsVisibleInProjectView));
} 

public bool IsDeleted 
{
    get { return Model.IsDeleted; }
    set 
    { 
        Model.IsDeleted = value; 
        OnPropertyChanged("IsDeleted");
        UpdateVisibility(); // This will change your IsVisibleInProjectView and notify the UI
    }
}  

...
```

This [tutorial](http://rachel53461.wordpress.com/2011/05/08/simplemvvmexample/) by Rachel also helped me a lot when I was learning MVVM.