# Wpf application with a fixed panel

Tags: wpf, xaml

I need to create a Wpf application with this type of navigation:

A main screen with a fixed top panel, and the rest of the window that acts as a container for other views. The container can be populated with 0 or 1 views - there's never a situation when 2 or more windows should be seen at the time in this container.

I've added this very childish drawing I made:

The top green panel is the navigation panel, and when pressing "A" button, I need viewA to be opened in the red part of the window.
Similarly, when pressing "B" button, I need viewB to be opened in the red part of the window instead of viewA.

[image]

My questions:

1. What objects should I use to represent viewA, viewB and the containing window? Are these Windows? Pages?
2. What is the best way of switching between viewA and viewB? I prefer avoiding loading both viewA and viewB (and any other view I'll have) into memory and just hide\show them..

Thanks.

Comment: What exactly is your programming question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put all the "Green" stuff in directly in your window and "Red" stuff (UserControl likely) inside a ContentControl and then bind the Content property of that to the red's stuff.  So it'd be like this:

```
<Window x:Class="garbage.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition Height="3*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition />
        <ColumnDefinition />
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <!--Green stuff-->
        <Button Content="A" />
        <Button Content="B" Grid.Column="1"/>
    <ContentControl Grid.Row="1" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Content="{Binding RedStuff}">
    </ContentControl>
</Grid>
```

Comment: This is what I was looking for: `ContentControl`. Thanks. After Googling for this control name, I found this complete example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15960843/501560.